# How to query Mongo using Timestamp that has a timezone?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following timestamp field in all my docs of a collection

`{"time_stamp": "2017-09-03T20:49:41.986-07:00"}` I believe this is in EDT although I am not entirely sure.

I need a way to do `$lte`, `$gte` comparsions. Is it possible ?

I am using mongo shell

I tried the following

`db.test.find({"time_stamp": 
                   {"$gte": new ISODate("2017-09-03T10:49:41.986-07:00")}
             })`

but it returned no documents

Comment: a quick search online brings up lots of examples of how to do this

Comment: @robjwilkins I did. However I see bunch of ISO Date examples. Not sure if that works in my case. Could you please point a link ? so I can delete my question ?

Comment: can you post some examples of queries you have tried perhaps we can see where you're going wrong

Comment: @robjwilkins just edited my question

Comment: Can you try this ?
`db.test.find({"time_stamp": 
                   {"$gte":"2017-09-03T10:49:41.986-07:00"}
             })`. It worked for me!

Comment: Is the problem that you have stood the date in the database as a string, rather than a date?

Comment: @harshavmb Thanks! works!

Comment: @robjwilkins yes its a timestamp that is of type string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare as a string rather than a date!

`db.test.find({"time_stamp": {"$gte":"2017-09-03T10:49:41.986-07:00"} })`